# What is a good API port standard for a MS Dynamic CRM SDK middle-tier interface?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a general MS Dynamic CRM (2013 on-premises) SDK middle-tier interface, so our customer can use our middle-tier interface to lively read, update, create, delete data from MS Dynamic CRM SDK. Our customer may connect our middle-tier with different system, for example a Java powered software, or a XML. So for building the API port of middle-tier interface, what is a good standard? May be XML with https? I am pretty new for this and this is a project for me, so I hope someone can explain more to me thanks.

Comment: Just curious why do you want to develop anything instead of usage of already available SOAP service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building your middle-tier interface component on .NET, you can use the Dynamics CRM SDK. Design your component around the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll and use the `IOrganizationService` interface to access the CRM platform.

You can start reading how this works on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309557.aspx). You may especially be interested in the topic "[Use the IOrganizationService web service to read and write data or metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx)".